# Moment converting datetime wrong

Tags: javascript, datetime, typescript, momentjs

I'm getting time from a datepicker. I select 15th july 2016 and when I check the variable of `sd` it is the 15th July 2016 00:00:00 GMT
After I populate the `filterDataSearchFilter.startDateTime` variable after the next line it's now saying 14-july-2016, rather than the 15th.

Why is this happening? Why is moment giving me `"2016-07-10T12:00:00.000Z"` and not `"2016-07-11T12:00:00.000Z"`

```
 goButtonSearchFilter() {
        debugger;
        if (this.filterDataSearchFilter.startDateTimeNonUtc != null) {
            var sd = this.filterDataSearchFilter.startDateTimeNonUtc.toString();
            this.filterDataSearchFilter.startDateTime = moment(this.filterDataSearchFilter.startDateTimeNonUtc).startOf('day').toISOString();
        }
```

Comment: `GMT New Zealand` is a contradiction.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  It's unclear why you'd want Noon UTC on *either* day.

Answer (score 0):

The issues isn't with moment, it's the toISOString() which fails to consider the timezone offset. Moment already gives you start of the day but isostring offsets the timezone therefore minuses that many hours, taking the day to previous one.

Hope this helps

Comment: `toISOString` *does* consider the offset - converting from local time to UTC before producing the result.  The `Date` object's version of `toISOString` works identically the same way.